# Unable to show the Tool Tip on the JavaFX TableView cell value

Tags: java, javafx-2

In my `JavaFX` `TableView` I have one `TableColumn` on which I have set Cell Factory to render `ProgressBar` and for other `TableColumn`s I have set Cell Factory to show `ToolTip`. Like the image below. Second Column is showing Progress Bar and other 3 Columns are render to show Tool tip, that has simple string values to show.

[image]

I was getting issue in which the `TableView` was not displaying/showing updated values in the table i.e UI is not validating/refreshing/painting the `TableView` elements. If I clicked on `ColumnHeader` to sort any column then only I can see the `TableView` updating. Manually sort the table column to refresh the table content is not making sense so I have searched and found solution to show/hide the Table Columns for updating the Table View.

To resolved the issue I have written a code below to solve the `TableView` Updating/Refreshing issue but due to this code now `ToolTip` are not getting visible.

**Code to Update Table View after each specific interval**

```
 class TableProgressBarUpdator implements Runnable {

        TableView table;

        public TableProgressBarUpdator(TableView fxtable) {
            table = fxtable;

        }

        public void start() {
            new Thread(this).start();
        }

        public void run() {

            while (keepUpdating) {
                try {
                    updateProgressbar();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LogHandler.doErrorLogging("Error while updating tables cell", e);
                }
            }
            LogHandler.doDebugLogging("Table process repainting is completed.");
        }

        private void updateProgressbar() throws Exception {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ((TableColumn) table.getColumns().get(0)).setVisible(false);
                    ((TableColumn) table.getColumns().get(0)).setVisible(true);
                }
            });


        }
    }
```

**Start Updating Table View**

```
public void startUpdatingTableProgress() {
    keepUpdating = true;
    TableProgressBarUpdator tpu = new TableProgressBarUpdator(table);
    tpu.start();
}
```

**Stop Updating Table View**

```
public void stopUpdatingTableProgress() {
        keepUpdating = false;
    }
```

**Adding more code that is showing render classes to show Progress bar and display Tool Tip.**

**Code to show the Progress Bar Table View.**

```
public static class ProgressBarTableCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T> {

        private final ProgressBar progressBar;
        private ObservableValue<T> ov;

        public ProgressBarTableCell() {
            this.progressBar = new ProgressBar();
            progressBar.setPrefHeight(23);
            setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null) {
                setGraphic(null);
                setText(null);
            } else {
                if (item.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Processing")) {
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            if (getGraphic() == null) {
                                setGraphic(progressBar);
                                progressBar.setProgress(-1);
                            } else {
                                ProgressBar objpProgressBar = (ProgressBar) getGraphic();
                                objpProgressBar.setProgress(-1);
                            }
                            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (getGraphic() == null) {
                                setGraphic(progressBar);
                                progressBar.setProgress(0);
                            } else {
                                ProgressBar objpProgressBar = (ProgressBar) getGraphic();
                                objpProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                            }
                            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Code to Show the Tool Tip**

```
public class ToolTip extends TableCell {

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Object object, boolean selected) {
            if (object == null) {
                setGraphic(null);
                setText(null);
            }else{
                setText(object.toString());
                setTooltip(new Tooltip(object.toString()));
            }
        }
    }
```

**Issue  -**

**If I comment-out these two lines from TableProgressBarUpdator Class then I am able to see Tool Tip for each cell values in 1st, 3rd and 4th column but now Table View contents are not updating/refreshing and when I UN-comment these lines I am unable to see the Tool Tip.**

```
((TableColumn) table.getColumns().get(0)).setVisible(false);
((TableColumn) table.getColumns().get(0)).setVisible(true);
```

In all due to these two lines my Tool Tip Render is not working and If I remove these two lines then Table View Content are not Refreshing/Updating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to update `TableView` manually. may be there are problem in your class associated with that `TableView's column`.

You have to create class as given below :

```
public static class Test{

private StringProperty name;

private Test() {
   name = new SimpleStringProperty();
}

public Test(String name) {
    this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name.set(name);
}

public String getName() {
    return name.get();
}

public StringProperty nameProperty() {
    return name;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need the Platform.runLater() call within your ProgressBarTableCell? I would expect it to already be in the Application thread.  That could cause the progress bar update to be placed at the end of the queue in the Application thread, after the scheduled table update.

Is the value for your TableCell wrapped in an ObservableProperty (looks like you should have an SimpleStringProperty)?  If you did, the table should recognize that it needs a refresh, and you shouldn't have to resort to toggling the column visibility as a hack to force table refreshing.

Comment: I have comment-out Platform.runLater() but still no luck. I am using SimpleStringProperty to set/get values and these values are associated with Columns.