# Is it possible to fill in a TableView's row with a new scene in Javafx?

Tags: java, javafx-2, tableview, javafx

I have a TableView that when I start download some file, it fills the row with a new scene from another fxml to show a status download, like the image below

[image]

Is it possible?? Do you have any suggestion how to do it, with or without using TableView?? Maybe using a GridPane?

Comment: why a scene? why not a simple node?

Comment: i think you need progress bar as on of  tabelview columns?

Comment: Sebastian, do you have any example code how to do that using node??

Comment: invariant, no no i need to fill the rows of my table using this status bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a `Scene` in a `TableView`. But you don't need to. Just create a custom `CellFactory` which produces `TableCell` with ProgressBar (or whatever controls you want) in it.

You can find an example here: [Unable to show the Tool Tip on the JavaFX TableView cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700580/unable-to-show-the-tool-tip-on-the-javafx-tableview-cell-value)